# Unable to view SSL certificate on magento frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl

[image]

I'm unable to view my SSL certificate on Magento frontend, i tried to change secure and unsecured url but still im getting like this. please anyone help me about this issue. im using 1.9.2.2 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems by looking at the urls the images are linked correctly but your settings aren't right - make sure your General > Web setttings look like this -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason for these errors are because the images are being served as http and not https.

My guess is that you have `CMS` Blocks and Pages that are referring to images as `http://` and not `https:`  check your CMS blocks to ensure that they are set correctly.

Other areas could be `CSS`, a manually inserted link on your site that was written as `http://` and not `https://`

In some instances some modules that aren't very well written are hard codded to do `http://` and not `https://`